# open("/dev/i2c-1",O_RDWR) return -1, i2c-1 device couldnt open

Tags: embedded, i2c, linux, android, java

I have a little problem about my app.

Firstly I install package i2c-tools,
I give all permission to all user for dev/i2c* files.
After, add the line `i2c-dev` in `etc/modules` file
i2c devices are exist in /dev/ directory.

I guess problem is in my C code: `int fd = open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR);` returns -1 value and it give `errno:2 No such file or directory.`

Anyone has a suggestions, whats the problem I couldnt found?
Below i2cdetect, device and permission output.

```
root@arge16-HP-600B:/home/arge1-6# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 37 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 49 -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: 50 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 59 -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  
root@arge16-HP-600B:/home/arge1-6# i2cdetect -l
i2c-0   i2c         i915 gmbus ssc                      I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c         i915 gmbus vga                      I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c         i915 gmbus panel                    I2C adapter
i2c-3   i2c         i915 gmbus dpc                      I2C adapter
i2c-4   i2c         i915 gmbus dpb                      I2C adapter
i2c-5   i2c         i915 gmbus dpd                      I2C adapter
i2c-6   i2c         DPDDC-B                             I2C adapter
root@arge16-HP-600B:/home/arge1-6# ls -l /dev/i2c*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root i2c 89, 0 Oct  2 14:36 /dev/i2c-0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root i2c 89, 1 Oct  2 14:36 /dev/i2c-1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root i2c 89, 2 Oct  2 14:36 /dev/i2c-2
crw-rw-rw- 1 root i2c 89, 3 Oct  2 14:36 /dev/i2c-3
crw-rw-rw- 1 root i2c 89, 4 Oct  2 14:36 /dev/i2c-4
crw-rw-rw- 1 root i2c 89, 5 Oct  2 14:36 /dev/i2c-5
crw-rw-rw- 1 root i2c 89, 6 Oct  2 14:36 /dev/i2c-6

root@arge16-HP-600B:/home/arge1-6/Desktop/ekrem/adt/workspaceEkrem/DIP40/IpIntercomDIP40# strace i2cdetect -y 1
execve("/usr/sbin/i2cdetect", ["i2cdetect", "-y", "1"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xf1a000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f53bc733000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=125548, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 125548, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f53bc714000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\36\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1853400, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3961912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f53bc14b000
mprotect(0x7f53bc308000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f53bc508000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bd000) = 0x7f53bc508000
mmap(0x7f53bc50e000, 17464, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f53bc50e000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f53bc713000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f53bc711000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f53bc711740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f53bc508000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x603000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f53bc735000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f53bc714000, 125548)          = 0
open("/dev/i2c/1", O_RDWR)              = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR)              = 3
ioctl(3, 0x705, 0x7fff039b01d8)         = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f53bc732000
write(1, "     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  "..., 52     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
) = 52
write(1, "00: ", 400: )                     = 4
write(1, "   ", 3   )                      = 3
write(1, "   ", 3   )                      = 3
write(1, "   ", 3   )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x3)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x4)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x5)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x6)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x7)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x8)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x9)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0xa)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0xb)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0xc)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0xd)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0xe)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0xf)                    = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- \n", 4-- 
)                    = 4
write(1, "10: ", 410: )                     = 4
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x10)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x11)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x12)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x13)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x14)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x15)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x16)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x17)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x18)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x19)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x1a)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x1b)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x1c)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x1d)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x1e)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x1f)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- \n", 4-- 
)                    = 4
write(1, "20: ", 420: )                     = 4
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x20)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x21)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x22)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x23)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x24)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x25)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x26)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x27)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x28)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x29)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x2a)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x2b)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x2c)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x2d)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x2e)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x2f)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- \n", 4-- 
)                    = 4
write(1, "30: ", 430: )                     = 4
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x30)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x31)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x32)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x33)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x34)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x35)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x36)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x37)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = 0
write(1, "37 ", 337 )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x38)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x39)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x3a)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x3b)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x3c)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x3d)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x3e)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x3f)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- \n", 4-- 
)                    = 4
write(1, "40: ", 440: )                     = 4
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x40)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x41)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x42)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x43)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x44)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x45)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x46)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x47)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x48)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x49)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = 0
write(1, "49 ", 349 )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x4a)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x4b)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x4c)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x4d)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x4e)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x4f)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- \n", 4-- 
)                    = 4
write(1, "50: ", 450: )                     = 4
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x50)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = 0
write(1, "50 ", 350 )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x51)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x52)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x53)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x54)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x55)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x56)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x57)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x58)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x59)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = 0
write(1, "59 ", 359 )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x5a)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x5b)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x5c)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x5d)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x5e)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x5f)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b00f0)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- \n", 4-- 
)                    = 4
write(1, "60: ", 460: )                     = 4
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x60)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x61)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x62)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x63)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x64)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x65)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x66)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x67)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x68)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x69)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x6a)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x6b)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x6c)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x6d)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x6e)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x6f)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- \n", 4-- 
)                    = 4
write(1, "70: ", 470: )                     = 4
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x70)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x71)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x72)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x73)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x74)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x75)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x76)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
ioctl(3, 0x703, 0x77)                   = 0
ioctl(3, 0x720, 0x7fff039b0120)         = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
write(1, "-- ", 3-- )                      = 3
write(1, "   ", 3   )                      = 3
write(1, "   ", 3   )                      = 3
write(1, "   ", 3   )                      = 3
write(1, "   ", 3   )                      = 3
write(1, "   ", 3   )                      = 3
write(1, "   ", 3   )                      = 3
write(1, "   ", 3   )                      = 3
write(1, "   \n", 4   
)                    = 4
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Try `strace i2cdetect -y 1` and see what it is *actually* doing, then compare your attempt.

Comment: I try your suggestion and edit questions `access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: In fact my program is an android apk. I use java native interface so I call a function in java from C. `Strace` is a function as Logcat in android?  How I use strace for  android apk>? Now what can I do?

Comment: But something continues to look very suspicious - you tested from a prompt "root@arge16-HP-600B".  An HP-600B is a tower PC which sounds a lot more like a development system than an embedded / Android device.  **Did you actually run i2c-detect on the exact same system (hardware and software) where you were trying your android apk???**.

Comment: 'arge16-HP-600B' is my pc name, not a development system. I run my apk in eclipse.Apk run on android virtual device. I got this error in logcatWindow in eclipse. I give all permission to all user.  i2c-detect working with unprivileged user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have run i2c-detect on your HP-600B PC, not on your Android virtual device.

**Apparently your android virtual device, like most, has no i2c capability** or at least none exposed to ordinary users in /dev.

You can explore the android device to some degree from the `adb shell` though ultimately to see the same type of restricted view and filesystem mounts as available to your app you will need to use a file browser app, local terminal app such as connectbot or an ssh server app.

Running tests on a PC can indeed be a shortcut when trying to understand how something *might* work, **but only tests run on the target system itself are definitive as to what is actually supported by it**.